# copy colored cells every minute to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with DDE link, it is simultaneously changing. It has a conditional formatting on Column A, with some criteria and changing the color of A column cells. I want to copy all Rows which of A column cells are coloured to another Sheet with VBA every 1 minute.

I tried below code but it is pasting to end every minute, i want to see the just coloured rows very minute.

```
Sub color()

Dim TransIDField As Range
Dim TransIDCell As Range
Dim ATransWS As Worksheet
Dim HTransWS As Worksheet

Set ATransWS = Worksheets("XU100")
Set TransIDField = ATransWS.Range("A2", ATransWS.Range("A2").End(xlDown))
Set HTransWS = Worksheets("DASHBOARD")


For Each TransIDCell In TransIDField

    If TransIDCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
        
        TransIDCell.Resize(1, 10).Copy Destination:= _
            HTransWS.Range("A1").Offset(HTransWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            
    End If

Next TransIDCell

HTransWS.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the condition in the conditional formatting?

Comment: `Range.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` would be the color applied by conditional formatting.

Comment: If  A column is higher then the 20 percentile of 20 days value, it changes the color of A Column.

Comment: Access the `Interior.Color` as mentioned by @BigBen **OR** just test the condition with the raw data rather relying on the color. You are essentially using color as a middle man test when you could just test the same logic. What is the formula you are using/

Answer (score 0):

**You can avoid copying by color by just testing the same logic used to color them in the first place**

1. Determine sheets & scope (last rows)
2. Determine the 20th percentile of range
3. Filter raw data for values larger than 20th percentile
4. Copy/Paste the filtered values to `DASHBOARD`

I think this approach is a little more explicit and also ensures your macro will not be impacted if your conditional formatting breaks. I find that conditional formats break due to user error from time to time which will impact all down stream dependencies.

---

```
Sub Try()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("XU100")
Dim ps As Worksheet: Set ps = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")
Dim lr As Long, Target As Double, lr2 As Long
Dim CopyMe As Range

lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lr2 = ps.Range("A" & ps.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Target = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile_Exc(ws.Range("A2:A" & lr), 0.8)

ws.AutoFilterMode = False

    Set CopyMe = ws.Range("A1:A" & lr)
    CopyMe.AutoFilter 1, ">" & Target
    CopyMe.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    ps.Range("A" & lr2 + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

ws.AutoFilterMode = False


End Sub
```

---

You may also want to check that `CopyMe` is not a blank range beforey trying to work with it. i.e. `If Not CopyMe is Nothing Then [Copy & Paste] End If`

Comment: Thank you for help. I dont know VBA too much. I am trying to highlight rows if E column is 80 percentile of Y column. I try to change these part with E and Y column but it does not work.

Target = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile_Exc(ws.Range("A2:A" & lr), 0.8)